# Conditionally exclude project creation in a multi-project Visual Studio project template

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, wizard, project-template, multi-project

I have a **multi-project** Visual Studio project template. I want to be able to, conditionally, exclude specific projects from the created solution.

I've looked into the **ProjectFinishedGenerating** method of my IWizard implementation, but I can't seem to figure out how to simply ignore a project.

So, essentially I want to do something like this pseudo-code in my IWizard implementation for projects:

```
public void ProjectFinishedGenerating(Project project)
{
   if(ExcludeAcmeProject && project.Name=="Acme"))
   {
      project.Cancel();
   }
}
```

Comment: I've tried the **Delete()** method, but it throws a **NotImplementedException**... :/

Comment: I think I figured it out. I can look at the **customParams** parameter in the **RunStarted** method (it contains the path of the .vstemplate file) and throw a **WizardCancelledException**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I can look at the **customParams** parameter in the **RunStarted** method (it contains the path of the .vstemplate file) and throw a WizardCancelledException if I want to skip that specific project.

Comment: Hello, Can you help me with this requirement? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60220136/how-to-add-conditions-in-visual-studio-template-schema-and-generate-projects-bas